# Android Temporary file - Life cycle

Tags: android, file, lifecycle, temporary

What is the life cycle of Temporary file in Android?

Who is responsible for their clean up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found out that I have to do it by my self, so I am running this clear cache method each time I start my app.

```
private static final long MIN_FREE_BYTES = 1024 * 1024 * 5; // this is 5M, Android recommend that there will always remind at last 1M
    public static void cleareCache(File directory){
        if(directory == null){
            directory = AppGenManager.getInstance().getCacheDir();
        }
        if(checkRemindingSpace(directory.getPath()) > MIN_FREE_BYTES){
            return;
        }

        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files){
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    cleareCache(file);
                }
                else{
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param path file path
     * @return the number of available bytes on this directory
     */
    private static long checkRemindingSpace(String path){
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return availableBlocks * blockSize;
    }
```